# downloading and working with ICS-file via eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, download, icalendar

I want to download an **ics** file with a hyperlink (it's updated permanently, so I always need the latest version) via eclipse, after it is available I want to read out the file, so I can work with it. 
And if the file needs to be downloaded to the file system, I want to delete it in the end again.
Unfortunatly I did not find any help in the internet yet and I do not know how to do it.

Sample ICS url: `americanhistorycalendar.com/peoplecalendar/1,328-abraham-lincoln?format=ical`

I hope someone can help. Just tell me, if you need more information.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem:

```
public String readICS() throws IOException {
    String fileUrl = "http://..."; //ICS-Url
    BufferedInputStream in = null;
    String ics = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(fileUrl).openStream());
        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        while (in.read(data, 0, 1024) != -1) {
            ics = ics + new String(data);
        }
     } finally {
         if (in != null)
             in.close();
    }
    return ics;
}
```